# python - composition (not inheritance) - main_instance.anotherClass.funct? How?

Tags: python

I have a class like this

```
class MainClass():
    blah blah blah

class AnotherClass():
    def __init__(self, main_class):
          self.main_class = main_class

    def required_method(self):
          blah blah blah
```

I donno much about how to use compostion(not inheritance), but I think I have to do something like above.

My requirement is:

I should be able to call functions of AnotherClass() using the instance of MainClass like this:

```
main_class.AnotherClass.required_method()
```

As of now, I am able to do this:

```
 main_class = MainClass()
 another = AnotherClass(main_class)
 another.required_method()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MainClass():
    def __init__(self, another_class):
      self.another_class = another_class

class AnotherClass():

    def required_method(self):
       blah blah blah

another = AnotherClass()
main_class = MainClass(another_class)
main_class.another_class.required_method()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use composition, it's mostly because you want to hide some classes functionality into another class:

```
class ComplexClass(object):
    def __init__(self, component):
        self._component = component

    def hello(self):
        self._component.hello()

class Component(object):
    def hello(self):
        print "I am a Component" 

class AnotherComponent(object):
    def hello(self):
        print "I am a AnotherComponent" 


>>> complex = ComplexClass(Component()):
>>> complex.hello()
>>> I am a Component
>>> complex = ComplexClass(AnotherComponent()):
>>> complex.hello()
>>> I am a AnotherComponent
```

Here `ComplexClass` uses a `Component`, but the user of `ComplexClass` does not need to know (and should not) what it does with the `Component`.

Of course, you can always

```
complex._component.hello()
```

when `complex` is just a container for other objects (then `_component` [should be](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) `component`). It is OK, but that is not the point of [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)

Comment: Can you please try without passing that class instance as parameter. I should be able to call complexclass_instance.Component.hello()